# CSS Text word break With overflow

Tags: html, css, line, word-break

Hey I want To make my text to break word and get only the first break word like make the the second break word and the rest to be hidden.

This is the site for the code: [here](http://jsfiddle.net/asskilled21/eDF8P/)

This is the part i want to be edit. ignore the other code in the jsfiddle.

```
.rpwe-block a{
color:#9d6745;
text-decoration:none;
clear: both;
text-overflow:ellipsis;
 overflow: hidden; white-space: nowrap;
}
```

I just want you to help me in editing this code I have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get rid of `white-space: no-wrap` from `.rpwe-block a` and add the following:

```
.rpwe-title{
  height: 14px;
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For the `overflow: hidden` to work the element would need a width (by default `a` tags are inline elements)

```
.rpwe-block a{
color:#9d6745;
text-decoration:none;
clear: both;
text-overflow:ellipsis;
overflow: hidden; white-space: nowrap;
width: 100%;
display: block;
}
```